# I'm having trouble with creating a responsive robot

Tags: java, eclipse

I have been working on a simple robot that responds only to certain things, but if it doesn't understand, tell the user that. I have two questions. I am using the switch function for this, and wanted to set the default to the robot not understanding. When I try to launch the program, I notice that the robot says that it doesn't understand immediately, before I even enter anything. How would I do this in a way that the default case happens only after the user has entered something. I tried using

```
if(!userInput=null) {
```

then the switch statement follows, but that gives me an error because it says it is not a boolean.

One more question. There is also an problem with the variable, userInput. Eclipse says "Resource Leak: userInput is never closed" Does anyone know how to fix this? Here is my current code:

```
package com.robot;

import java.util.Scanner;
public class Robot {

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);

    switch(userInput.toString()) {

        case "hello": 
            robotSay("hello");
            break;
        case "hi":
            robotSay("hi");
            break;
        case "hey":
            robotSay("hello");
            break;
        default:
            robotSay("I do not understand");
            break;
    }


}
public static void robotSay(String string) 
{
    System.out.println(string);
}
}
```

Comment: You have to use the read method of the scanner!

Comment: Scanner.toString() doesn't read what the user entered. Read the javadoc.

Comment: `if(!userInput=null)` should be `if(userInput != null)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use

```
switch(userInput.nextLine()) {
```

`.nextLine()` returns the first unread line in `System.in` (and waits for input if necessary).

`.toString()` returns a String representation of the object, in you case it would lock something like this:

```
java.util.Scanner[delimiters=\p{javaWhitespace}+][position=0][match valid=false][need input=false][source closed=false][skipped=false][group separator=\.][decimal separator=\,][positive prefix=][negative prefix=\Q-\E][positive suffix=][negative suffix=][NaN string=\Q�\E][infinity string=\Q∞\E]
```

---

the ResourceLeak is created, because you never close the InputStream (inside the Scanner), so that resource will be unavailable to other programs until your program finishes.

Just do

```
userInput.close();
```

in the end.

Comment: Thank you! It almost works now! Just one more thing. For some reason, the console wont let me type more than 2 things before eclipse says <terminated>

Comment: @Eman11 you don't have any loop in your code. You read the next line, answer, and the the main function ends. You need a loop to ask for input repeatedly.

Comment: where do I start and end the loop(I am new to Java)

Comment: any loop needs to include the `userInput.nextLine()` (to look for new inputs)  and the `switch` (to evaluate them). Example: `for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {\n switch (userInput.nextLine()) {...}\n}` (without the "\n")

Comment: I tried including the while loop starting before the switch then ends after the switch and after I close userInput. Eclipse said:                                                                         Exception in thread "main" 
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Scanner closed
 at java.util.Scanner.ensureOpen(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.Scanner.findWithinHorizon(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.Scanner.nextLine(Unknown Source)
 at com.robot.Robot.main(Robot.java:13)

Comment: Obvious problem: `close()` closes the input. Then the `while` jumps back to `nextLine()` now throwing an Exception, because the input is closed.

Comment: I am confused. If I ended the while loop before userInput.close(), it would be unreachable code.

Comment: are you doing `while (true)`? if so, your program can't be closed (and this Resource-thing won't ever be a problem, because the OS forces applications to release all resources on termination). I'd recommend implementing something like `boolean running = true; while (running) {[some way to set running to false]}`

Answer (score 0):

You need to use String input = userInput.next(); before switch statement and use switch (input) so that the scanner will wait for user input and read it before executing switch.

After the switch you need to use userInput.close() in order to close the scanner that will make the error go away.

Comment: @Everyone, I made a youtube video explaining this but a better version. Please check it out: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NE-DeZAYGWI&list=PLeFmSs81qaMA11plgpyArvQSryuPWiVEf